# Executing a system command in Java application

Tags: java, console

I was trying to execute a system command in a Java application with the use of `Runtime exec` and `Process`. I've made a simple program of it just for demonstration and the example command is the `javac`, which simply compiles a Java program. Using the application, just choose the file to be compiled and select the output folder where it'll be saved later.

Here's the full program code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    private static JFileChooser jFileChooser1, jFileChooser2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(238, 62);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(null);

        jFileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();
        jFileChooser2 = new JFileChooser();


        JButton jButton1 = new JButton("File");
        jButton1.setBounds(1, 1, 70, 25);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jFileChooser1.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
                jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(jFrame);
            }
        });
        jPanel.add(jButton1);


        JButton jButton2 = new JButton("Folder");
        jButton2.setBounds(75, 1, 70, 25);
        jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jFileChooser2.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
                jFileChooser2.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                jFileChooser2.showOpenDialog(jFrame);
            }
        });
        jPanel.add(jButton2);


        JButton jButton3 = new JButton("Compile");
        jButton3.setBounds(149, 1, 80, 25);
        jButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                File selectedFile = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
                File selectedFolder = jFileChooser2.getSelectedFile();

                String s = null;

                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d " +selectedFolder+ " " +selectedFile);

                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

                    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        jPanel.add(jButton3);


        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But in the actual application I am developing, the system command I'm trying to execute requires a binary program which I want to keep inside the application (a local resource file). For example, it is in the `assets` package. So to access the resource file, I use this code:

```
URL binary = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("assets/binary.bin");
```

And the example usage/syntax of the command is something like:

```
"command -options " +binary+ " " +selectedFile+ " " +selectedFolder+ "
```

And in the program:

```
...
try {
    URL binary = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("assets/binary.bin");
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command -options " +binary+ " " +selectedFile+ " " +selectedFolder+ ");
    ...
}
```

But I'm getting an error when I try it in my IDE:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile file:/D:/Projects/Java/Test/build/classes/assets/binary.bin
```

So is this even possible? How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should use the ProcessBuilder and related class, and never use Runtime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is **not** possible.

You want to make a call to the *operating system*, telling it to run some executable somewhere.

But that somewhere must be something that the *operating system* has access to; in other words: something that exists on the local file system for example.

You might be able to workaround by fetching the content of your binary file from your JAR; and write it to some local temp directory.

So instead of pointing to some internal resource, your program has to first create a "temp" version of that binary; so you can then invoke that using *ProcessBuilder* (it is 2017; forget about Runtime.exec()); to finally delete that temp file later on.

Comment: Okay, love the 2017 part. Thank you! I am still a beginner in programming (just forgot to include it in the question). I'll go search for it. Thanks again :)

Comment: For the record: of course using ProcessBuilder is the "state of the art" way of doing such things; but that doesn't really affect your core question; as I think: it doesnt make a difference if you use Runtime.exec or a ProcessBuilder - in the end, you are not able to run a binary that exists only as resource somewhere in your classpath (wrapped up in some JAR file).

Comment: Yeah I get it now. Thank you so much! :)